# Sharepoint modifying code and adding .ExternalClass identifier automatically. Any way to prevent?

Tags: branding, publishing-page

Afer saving/ publishing Sharepoint keeps changing the following code
FROM THIS.....

```
A IMG {BORDER-BOTTOM: medium none; BORDER-LEFT: medium none; BORDER-TOP: medium none; BORDER-RIGHT: medium none}
```

TO THIS....

```
**.ExternalClass** A IMG {BORDER-BOTTOM: medium none; BORDER-LEFT: medium none; BORDER-TOP: medium none; BORDER-RIGHT: medium none}</style><style>
```

So it inserts the .ExternalClass  identifier and thus prohibits the code from working.
Does anyone know a workaround or way to prevent this code from changing?

Basically I'm trying to hide the left hand sidebar and hyperlink object borders from the page using the page source - no webparts.

thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I've had this happen to me with my stylesheets as well. For me, it happens most often when:

- The page that the CSS is on is Checked-In BEFORE Saving the page.

- A Check-Out is Discarded BEFORE Saving the page.

It has to do with SharePoint's "auto-correct" for code that thinks it is "helping."

I'm personally looking into having the CSS sheets in a separate file and somehow linking it to the pages. This would ideally put the sheet far away from the auto-correct and prevent further problems. I can keep you posted on if this works, but, until then, see if the two situations I had are involved in what's happening to yours.

***EDIT***
I recently found another question that someone asked about CSS stylesheets that solved my problem perfectly. ***It does involve WebParts though.***
Does your application of the stylesheet put it in an "Insert -> Embed Code"?

Instead, try using a Script Editor, found under the Web Parts -> Media and Content -> Script Editor. It encases the code in a kind of "auto-correct" shield that doesn't cause the .ExternalClass to be added.